# Cannot find symbol variable error

Tags: java

So I'm working on a program for an assignment for a programming class. Basically I'm suppose to be able to input letter grades and course hours which are then turned into grade values in GPA format. These grade values are then multiplied by the course hours to give the overall course value. All the course values are then added to give a total value and all the course hours are added to give total hours. Finally Overall GPA is given by dividing totalValue/total hours.

Now obviously I'm doing something wrong because when I try to compile the following wall of code I get 10 errors all very similar. I get a "cannot find symbol variable" error for all the cValues (cVal1,cVal2, etc.) and all the cHours and I have no idea why because I even declared them as public. I've even tried removing the "static" before them, declaring them as public, changing the parameter variables and I'm stumped. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class stlab09
{       

public static void main (String args[])                             
{   
    System.out.println("\nLAB09 90 POINT VERSION\n\n");
    enterData();
    computeGPA();
    displayData();
}

public static String lGrade1;
public static String lGrade2;
public static String lGrade3;
public static String lGrade4;
public static int cHours1; 
public static int cHours2;
public static int cHours3;
public static int cHours4;
public static String dummy;
public static double gpa;
public static int cVal1;
public static int cVal2;
public static int cVal3;
public static int cVal4;

public static void enterData()
{       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.print("Enter course 1 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade1 = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("enter course 1 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours1 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter course 2 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade2 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter course 2 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours2 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter course 3 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade3 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter course 3 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours3 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter course 4 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade4 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter course 4 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours4 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
}

public static void computeGPA()
{
    int gVal1 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade1);
    int gVal2 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade2);
    int gVal3 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade3);
    int gVal4 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade4);
    int cVal1 = Grades.courseValue(gVal1, cHours1);
    int cVal2 = Grades.courseValue(gVal2, cHours2);
    int cVal3 = Grades.courseValue(gVal3, cHours3);
    int cVal4 = Grades.courseValue(gVal4, cHours4);
}

public static void displayData()
{   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Course1 Grade: " + lGrade1 +  "  Course1 Credit Hours: " + cHours1);
    System.out.println("Course2 Grade: " + lGrade2 +  "  Course2 Credit Hours: " + cHours2);
    System.out.println("Course3 Grade: " + lGrade3 +  "  Course3 Credit Hours: " + cHours3);
    System.out.println("Course4 Grade: " + lGrade4 +  "  Course4 Credit Hours: " + cHours4);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current GPA: " + gpa);
}
}

class Grades
{
public static int gradeValue(String letterGrade)
{
    char lg = letterGrade.charAt(0);
    int value = 0;
    switch(lg)
    {
        case 'A':  value = 4;  break;
        case 'B':  value = 3;  break;
        case 'C':  value = 2;  break;
        case 'D':  value = 1;  break;
        case 'F':  value = 0;  break;
    }

    return value;
}

public static int courseValue(int a, int b)
{ 
    int cValue = a * b;

}

public static void getGPA()
{
    double totalValue = cVal1 + cVal2 + cVal3 + cVal4;   ***<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE***
    double totalHours = cHours1 + cHours2 + cHours3 + cHours4;  ***<<ERROR HERE***
    double gpa = totalValue / totalHours;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
public static void computeGPA()
{
int gVal1 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade1);
int gVal2 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade2);
int gVal3 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade3);
int gVal4 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade4);
int cVal1 = Grades.courseValue(gVal1, cHours1);
int cVal2 = Grades.courseValue(gVal2, cHours2);
int cVal3 = Grades.courseValue(gVal3, cHours3);
int cVal4 = Grades.courseValue(gVal4, cHours4);
}
```

you are defining cVal1 etc as local variables, they can not be seen outside of this method.
Try  using the class scoped variables (remove the ints).

As in

```
public static void computeGPA()
{
int gVal1 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade1);
int gVal2 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade2);
int gVal3 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade3);
int gVal4 = Grades.gradeValue(lGrade4);
cVal1 = Grades.courseValue(gVal1, cHours1);
cVal2 = Grades.courseValue(gVal2, cHours2);
cVal3 = Grades.courseValue(gVal3, cHours3);
cVal4 = Grades.courseValue(gVal4, cHours4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cvals are members of first class, not the Grade.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems in your code:

1.You are trying to access those variables in `getGPA()` of class **Grades**, but they belong to class **stlab09**

2.In `computeGPA()` of class **stlab09**, you don't need to declare all of those variables again: `int cVal1 = ...`, please get rid of the beginning `int`, otherwise it will override your static variable cVal1.